# Change of design of queries to improve performance

Tags: java, sql-server, performance

This is more like a design question but related to SQL optimization as well.

My project has to import a large number of records into the database (more than 100k records). In the meantime, the project has logic to check each record to make sure it meets the criteria which are configurable. It then will mark the record as no warning or has warning in the database. The inserting and warning checking are done within one importing process.

For each criteria it has to query the database. The query needs to join two other tables and sometimes add additional nested query inside the conditions, such as

```
select * from TableA a 
  join TableB on ... 
  join TableC on ... 
where
  (select count(*) from TableA 
where TableA.Field = Bla) > 100
```

Although the queries take unnoticeable time, to query the entire record set takes a considerable amount of time which may be 4 - 5 hours on a server. Especially if there are many criteria, at the end the project will stop running the import and rollback.

I've tried changing "SELECT * FROM" to "SELECT TableA.ID FROM" but it seems it has no effect at all. Is there a better design to improve the performance of this process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about making a temp table (or more than one) that stores the aggregated results of the sub-queries, then indexing that/those with covering indexes.

From your code above, we'd make a temp table grouping on TableA.Field1 and including a count, then index on Field1, theCount.  On SQL server the fastest approach would then be:

```
select * from TableA a 
  join TableB on ... 
  join TableC on ... 
  join (select Field1 from #temp1 where theCount > 100) t on...
```

The reason this works is that we are doing the same trick twice.

First, we pre-aggregate into the temp table, which is a simple operation and very easy for SQL Server to optimize.  So we have taken a piece of the problem and solved in an optimizable way.

Then we repeat this trick by joining to a subquery, putting the filter inside the subquery, so that the join acts as a filter.

Comment: Where should I make the temp table? The "(select count(*) from TableA where TableA.Field1 = Bla and TableA.Field2=Blaa and...)" query is also from the database so I have to figure out a way to convert it into a temp table first.

Comment: I'm assuming you are doing this in stages.  First, the 100k rows are loaded to an "inbox" table, or staging table.  Next you are pulling out of that table in one or more steps to get the data to its ultimate destination.  Therefore, the temp table can be created either in a stored procedure or in application code.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you batch your records together (500 or so at a time) and send it to a stored proc which can do the calculation.

Use simple statements instead of joins in there. That saves as well. This [link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/tips/dm-0403wilkins/) might help as well.

Answer (score 0):

Good choice is using indexed view. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd171921(SQL.100).aspx